# Entity Framework 4.0 won't let me use LINQ-to-Entities

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Maybe I'm somewhat over-worked ... I'm lost in a project where I use EF4 for the DB stuff.

As such, it does work indeed well to retrieve a complete list of an entity.
But when I try to do some filtering, I don't get it...

I have the following code, where I get in big trouble

```
public class InfoViewModel
{
    private TrackerEntities _context;

    public InfoViewModel (int ticketID)
    {
        var ct = new TrackerEntities();
        var res = from t in ct.Tickets
                  where t.TicketID    // VS2010 can't evaluate the property 'TicketID'
                  select t;
 }
}
```

I do not understand why t.TicketID throws me the wavy red line with the error message
"Can not resolve symbol 'TicketID'"

The symbol is declared in the EDMX file, with public getter and setter...

In fact, it looks like nothing of the entity is known in my class.

Why?

TIA
DeepCore

Comment: Does it compile, or do you get the same error on build?

Comment: No, it doesn't compile... it throws the following error message:
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh...

I'm feeling really dumb... I have found my mistake!

Somehow the following using statement went missing :o(

```
using System.Linq
```

I think, I have to ask for some vacation.

Thank you all for investing your time to help me!

DeepCore

Answer (score 4):

1) you should compare the TicketID of the entity with the desired match, and (recommended) you should wrap the context instance in a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) (it's [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)):

`private TrackerEntities _context;`

`public InfoViewModel(int ticketID)

{

var ct = new TrackerEntities();

var res = from t in ct.Tickets

where`**`t.TicketID == ticketID`**
`select t;

}`

2) Try refreshing the model; go to the EDM designer, right click the surface and select "Update Model from Database", maybe there is an error in the schema.

3) Make sure the `TicketID` property is the same spelling and casing as in the EDM.

4) Make sure the `TicketID` is `int` **and** compare it to another int as in the updated snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to IDisposable!
Refreshing the model didn't help.
I also re-checked the spelling and casing... they are the same as in the EDM.